# trying to find "top n" but getting some errors with dates

Tags: mysql

Let's say I am trying to find the top 10 icecream flavors sold by a store starting from this month. My current query however only gives me the top ten flavors from 7/01

```
select *
from buy_history
where date > '2012-07-01 00:00:00' 
group by flavor
order by max(purchase_count) desc 
limit 10;
```

(yes apparently there can be multiple icecream purchases per millisecond.)

the table looks something like
`buy_history(id, flavor, date, purchase_count)`

Comment: Are you trying to order by the purchase count aggregated by day or month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select flavor, sum(purchase_count) as purchase_count_total
from buy_history 
where date >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-' MONTH(CURDATE()), '-1')
group by flavor 
order by sum(purchase_count) desc 
limit 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using below for the date condition

```
WHERE month(date)=3
```

Comment: nope, same thing. only displays numbers from the first of march.

Answer (score 0):

It only appears that way. Make a manual count (or get it into a spreadsheet and calculate and verify).

The problem here is that you are grouping the results by a certain column (`group by flavor`) and your results have additional columns that is neither included in the `group by` clause or in an aggregate function. MySQL does not know therefore how to display those columns (which one does the server pick to display).

You should do this instead (*roughly):

```
select flavor, sum(purchase_count) as total_sold
from buy_history
where date > '2012-07-01 00:00:00' 
group by flavor
order by total_sold desc 
limit 10;
```